# Change the prop of another component after clicking on a different component in Sveltekit

Tags: tailwind-css, sveltekit

Problem - I have created a card component in Sveltekit using tailwind and then I show four iterations of the card component on a dashboard page. I want to click on a card component and change the background colour and set it as *active*. I can set the status as active and change the background colour when clicking on one of the cards, but I can't toggle the active state of the previously selected active card when I click on another one.

The other problem with my implementation is if a user clicks on a card that's active, it toggles the active card as not active which I want to prevent too.

My card component is

```
<script>
    export let mainData;
    export let subData;
    export let symbol;
    export let active = false;

    const setActive = () => {
         active = !active
    }

</script>

<div class="p-6 rounded-md border-blue-grey-200 drop-shadow-md cursor-pointer group" on:click={setActive} class:bg-white={!active} class:bg-cyan-700={active} class:hover:bg-cyan-400={!active} class:hover:bg-cyan-700={active} class:hover:drop-shadow-2xl={!active} >
    <p class="mb-1 font-normal group-hover:text-white" class:text-blue-grey-800={!active} class:text-white={active}>{subData}</p>
    <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-blue-grey-800 group-hover:text-white" class:text-blue-grey-800={!active} class:text-white={active}>{mainData} <span class="mb-3 text-xl font-normal tracking-tight text-blue-grey-800 group-hover:text-white" class:text-blue-grey-800={!active} class:text-white={active}>{symbol}</span></h5>
</div>
```

And then I add the Card component to the dashboard like this:

```
<div class="flex flex-row mt-6 space-x-6" >
        <div class="basis-1/4">
            <Card  mainData = {uk_cost} subData = 'UK' symbol = '£' active=true/>
        </div>
        <div class="basis-1/4">
            <Card  mainData = {us_cost} subData = 'US' symbol = '$'/>
        </div>
        <div class="basis-1/4">
            <Card  mainData = {euro_cost} subData = 'Europe' symbol = '€'/>
        </div>
        <div class="basis-1/4">
            <Card  mainData = {japan_cost} subData = 'Japan' symbol = '¥'/>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, are you basically looking to implement radio buttons, but with cards as choices?

Comment: That's a great way of looking at it - I didn't think about that as a possibility

Comment: I've configured the cards as radio buttons, assigned a value to each one and bound them to a group, but I can't modify the active state of the card?

Comment: I used the $ syntax to listen to the bind:group and then handled the value that was passed in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using some hard-coding but with some nominal changes, and you might be able to make it dynamic if that is your requirement.  (This is not the "radio button" method, though that could be an alternate solution.)

Note: I'm not a pro with Svelte.  I also added some dummy values for the REPL.

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/3bda79e24c124204a1b839ad3124ad29?version=3.46.5

```
<script>
    import Card from "./Card.svelte";
    let current;
</script>

<div class="flex flex-row mt-6 space-x-6">

    <div class="basis-1/4">
        <button on:click="{() => current = 'UK'}">
            <Card mainData='1' subData='UK' symbol='£' 
                      active="{current === 'UK'}"/>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="basis-1/4">
        <button on:click="{() => current = 'US'}">
            <Card mainData='333' subData='US' symbol='$'
                      active="{current === 'US'}"/>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="basis-1/4">
        <button on:click="{() => current = 'Europe'}">
            <Card mainData='22' subData='Europe' symbol='€'
                      active="{current === 'Europe'}"/>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="basis-1/4">
        <button on:click="{() => current = 'Japan'}">
            <Card mainData='523' subData='Japan' symbol='¥'
                      active="{current === 'Japan'}"/>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Card.svelte is a little simpler:

```
<script>
    export let mainData;
    export let subData;
    export let symbol;
    export let active = false;
</script>

<div class="p-6 rounded-md border-blue-grey-200 drop-shadow-md cursor-pointer group"
     class:bg-white={!active} class:bg-cyan-700={active} class:hover:bg-cyan-400={!active}
     class:hover:bg-cyan-700={active} class:hover:drop-shadow-2xl={!active}>
    <p class="mb-1 font-normal group-hover:text-white" class:text-blue-grey-800={!active}
       class:text-white={active}>{subData}</p>
      <p>Toggled ACTIVE? {active}</p>
    <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-blue-grey-800 group-hover:text-white"
        class:text-blue-grey-800={!active} class:text-white={active}>{mainData} <span
            class="mb-3 text-xl font-normal tracking-tight text-blue-grey-800 group-hover:text-white"
            class:text-blue-grey-800={!active} class:text-white={active}>{symbol}</span></h5>
</div>
```